# WinSCP - Doing post-processing in a BAT file

Tags: batch-file, winscp

Here's what I want to do using WinSCP called from a BAT file:

1. Execute a WinSCP script that uploads files to an FTP site.
2. Test the success of the upload.
3. If successful, move the files on the local machine to another folder.
4. If unsuccessful, do nothing.

I have tried the example batch file shown at the WinSCP site, but after the WinSCP command is executing, the remainder of the bat file is ignored.

See:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload

Comment: Do not link to code. Please edit your question and provide the exact code you are using.

Answer (score 2):

[The official example](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload#scripting) was missing `exit` command at the end of the WinSCP script.

It should be:

```
# Connect
open mysession
# Upload the files
put *.*
# Exit WinSCP
exit
```

Then the batch file will correctly process the other commands:

```
winscp.com /script=example.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

echo Upload succeeded, moving local files
move *.* c:\backup\
exit 0

:error
echo Upload failed, keeping local files
exit 1
```

---

I have corrected the example.

Comment: In my WinSCP script I had already added the exit command, and the batch file still didn't execute the code after the winscp command.

Comment: If you use a different code than in the example, you have to show us, as [already suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558304/winscp-doing-post-processing-in-a-bat-file/34558633?noredirect=1#comment56859998_34558304) + Any evidence for the problem. A screenshot, a log file, an output dump, anything.